# What is idr_alloc()

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

In the source code implementation it says `idr_alloc()` is used to allocate new `idr` entry. I couldn't find the `man page` and want to know why it is used especially when writing drivers for `MTD` devices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `idr` library is used in the kernel to manage assigning integer IDs to objects and looking up objects by id.  See this [LWN net article](https://lwn.net/Articles/103209/) for a full introduction; the basic idea is that you have the following operations:

- `idr_get_new(struct idr *idp, void *ptr, int *id)` -- assign a new ID for the pointer `ptr` and return it via `id`
- `void *idr_find(struct idr *idp, int id)` -- return the pointer corresponding to `id`
- `void idr_remove(struct idr *idp, int id)` -- clear the entry for `id`

This is useful anywhere a small integer ID that maps to a kernel object is useful -- eg minor numbers or other indexes that are returned to userspace.